# Integer solutions to $2^x-1=3^y$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, exponential-function, diophantine-equations, perfect-powers

Does anybody know how to solve it?
I know how to solve linear diophantine equations, but equation like this I've never seen before.
$$2^x-1=3^y.$$

Comment: This is the well known Catalan equation.

Answer (score 6):

This is a special case of [Mihăilescu's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_conjecture) (a.k.a. Catalan's conjecture) that has been illustrated here many times before. There are no nontrivial solutions to
$$2^x-3^y=1,$$
nontrivial meaning $x,y\geq2$.

**Proof:** Clearly $x,y\geq0$. If $x$ is even, say $x=2z$, then
$$3^y=2^x-1=(2^z-1)(2^z+1),$$
and so the two factors on the right hand side are two powers of $3$ that differ by $2$, which implies that $x=2$ and $y=1$.

If $x$ is odd then
$$3^y\equiv2^x-1\equiv1\pmod{3},$$
which implies $y=0$ and hence $x=1$.